# Find all filename.ext1 where no filename.ext2 exists in OS X or the shell

Tags: macos, shell-script

I need to create both TIF and JPG versions of a large set of images.

All JPG images already exist, but only a part of the TIF images. Is there an easy way to search a directory to find all JPG files that have no corresponding TIF file (i.e. a file with the same name but with different file extension)?

Comment: Wish I saw this earlier, asked a similar question today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl one-liner:

```
find . -name '*.jpg'|perl -nle 's/\.jpg//;unless(-f "$_.tif"){print "$_.jpg"}'
```

In 63 characters:

```
find . -name '*.jpg'|perl -pnle 's/.jpg//;-f "$_.tif"||"$_.jpg"'
```

Comment: Interesting... But when I tried it I got the following error (pls note that I don't know perl at all...): 

Anderss-MacBook-Pro:Temp Anders$ perl hello.pl
String found where operator expected at hello.pl line 2, near "name '*.jpg'"
 (Do you need to predeclare name?)
String found where operator expected at hello.pl line 2, near "pnle 's/.jpg//;-f "$_.tif"||"$_.jpg"'"
 (Do you need to predeclare pnle?)
syntax error at hello.pl line 2, near "name '*.jpg'"
Execution of hello.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I'm guessing you just left out something that you assumed I would know :-). BTW, is there any way of making this recursive to check subdirectories as well, with directory names printed out?

Comment: Woops, you run this from the command line, not from inside a perl script. Just cut and paste into terminal when you're in the directory w/ the images. This should cover subdirectories, but the files list as "directory/file1", "directory/file2", etc.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty nice! Actually, only the first one worked though, not the second one. That one only listed all the files... Shouldn't you be able to run this in a file though? I read a reeally short intro to perl, where you put the script in a .pl file and ran it from Terminal. That would be good to have in case I need to reuse it, instead of having to paste in this each time... Thanks

Comment: Yes, I realized later that the second one was broken. This is really a combination of Unix commands and perl. If you want, you can put it a file called "something.sh" and then do "sh something.sh" (or "bash something.sh"). If you have 'convert' (ImageMagick), you can even convert the jpgs to tiffs.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming all images are in the `images` directory and has the `.jpg` suffix, the following little script will print out all image files that has no corresponding `.tif` file on UNIX:

```
#!/bin/sh

find images/ -type f -name "*.jpg" |
while read j; do
  t=${j%.jpg}.tif
  if [ ! -f "$t" ]; then
    echo "Lacking tif file: " $j
  fi
done
```

Paste this to a file, and save it a folder above the one where your images are stored. You could call it `find-images`. For example:

```
├── find-images
└── images/
    ├── 1.jpg
    └── 2.jpg
    └── ...
```

Now, open *Utilities/Terminal.app*, and use the `cd` command to navigate to the folder where your script is, e.g. if the script is on your Desktop, just enter `cd Desktop`.

Then, enter `chmod +x find-images`. Now you can run the script by just calling `./find-images`.

Comment: Ok, this sounds sort of doable. I'm on a Mac, which is a kind of Unix, but I'm really new to the Mac. Do I put this script in Terminal or do I somehow create a script file (bash I suppose...)?

Comment: @AndersSvensson I added some information about how to run it. KAK, hope you don't mind.

Comment: This works nicely, and simple enough, thanks. Just a follow-up question: is there any simple way to make it recursive, and check all subdirectories as well? Preferably printing out the name of the directory, like in sections of the result file?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed it did actually check recursively... Just ran it on a test folder first which didn't have subdirs... I still have to choose the perl solution, because that worked with all files, this one failed on files with spaces in the names. Thanks though.

Comment: @slhck, no worries.

Comment: @AndersSvensson, strange, I tried it under both Korn shell and bash and it worked with files that had spaces in them. Maybe the OSX bash does something differently from the OpenBSD bash? I haven't set the `$IFS` variable to anything special, so I don't know what went wrong there.

Comment: It didn't work with filenames that have spaces because some variables weren't quoted... But I edited the script to quote them, and also changed it to print the full paths of files.

Answer (score 6):

I'll use Python, since it is cross-platform. First put your jpg and tif files in separate folders.

```
import os

jpgPath = "path/to/jpgs/folder"
tifPath = "path/to/tifs/folder"

jpgList = [item.rsplit(".", 1)[0] for item in os.listdir(jpgPath)]
tifList = [item.rsplit(".", 1)[0] for item in os.listdir(tifPath)]

diffList = [item for item in jpgList if item not in tifList]

print diffList
```

Then, save this script to a file, somewhere on your hard drive, maybe under the name `find-images`.

Now, open *Utilities/Terminal.app*, and enter `python /path/to/file`. For example, if you saved it on your Desktop, it would be `python ~/Desktop/find-images` (since `~` is a shortcut to your home folder). Here, you can run [a more detailed explanation](http://beckism.com/2008/05/run_python_mac_os_x/) on running Python files on your Mac.

Comment: You need to strip file extensions first, otherwise *none* of the files will match. I would guess `[item.rsplit(".", 1)[0] for item in os.listdir(jpgPath)]`...

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks, but I have no idea how to use Python. I'm on a Mac, would Python work in Terminal, or what do I do? @grawity: and where would I place this stripping of the extensions command?

Comment: @grawity Oh right. Silly me. Edited.
@AndersSvensson Python should be pre-installed on your mac. Just type `python` into Terminal and paste in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I felt like adding this. Here's the solution in Ruby, which prints every image that has no TIF counterpart:

```
jpg = Dir["*.jpg"]
tif = Dir["*.tif"]    
[jpg, tif].each { |a| a.map!{ |f| f[0..-5]} }
puts jpg - tif
```

Put it into a file which resides in the same folder as your images, save it as `find-images`, and run it in Terminal by entering `ruby find-images`.

<sub>If you don't know Ruby, don't ask how it works, might take a while to explain :P</sub>

Comment: A more generic version: `a0, a1 = ARGV[0], ARGV[1]; dir0 = Dir["*.#{a0}"]; dir1 = Dir["*.#{a1}"]; dir0.each {|f| puts f unless dir1.include?(f.sub(/\.#{a0}$/, ".#{a1}"))}`

Comment: @Lri Hah. Pretty neat. Still learning – the parallel assignment is something I have to use more often.

Answer (score 2):

### diffext

```
#!/bin/bash

found1=$(find "$PWD" -name "*.$1")
found2=$(find "$PWD" -name "*.$2")
export IFS=$'\n'
for f1 in "$found1"; do
    base1=${f1##/}
    for f2 in "$found2"; do
        base2=${f2##/}
        [[ ${base1%.$1} == ${base2%.$2} ]] && continue 2
    done
    echo "$f1"
done
```

- Usage: `cd somedir; diffext jpg tif`
- Searches recursively in subdirectories of the current directory

  - Treats files as duplicates even if they were in different directories

Answer (score 1):

One-liner(s) without perl:

With using while loop after find:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' | while read file ; do test ! -f `dirname $file`/`basename $file .jpg`.tif && echo $file; done
```

With using (lots of) subshells:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'test ! -f `echo {} |sed s/\.jpg$/.flac/` && echo {}' \;
```

Comment: This would work with file names that have spaces and print the absolute paths: `diffexts() { find "$PWD" -name "*.$1" | while read f; do [[ ! -e ${f%.$1}.$2 ]] && echo "$f"; done; }`